# Running NSRunningApplication isActive using raw libproc

Tags: objective-c, c, macos

In Objective-C, it's possible to get a list of all running processes using the shared NSWorkspace, e.g:
NSRunningApplication *currApp in [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications]

You can then loop through each individual NSRunningApplication, and check if a specific process is currently the active one (directly being used by the user) using the NSRunningApplication isActive method. If you're currently browsing the web in chrome, the active process would be the one used by that chrome instance.

In a similar way, you can loop through all the currently active processes using libproc, via proc_listpids. I see that libproc provides access to low level process information, such as process name, number of threads, CPU usage, task priority, etc. Much like what activity monitor shows in OSX.

Is there a way of seeing via libproc if a specific process is the currently active one? I assume that the NSRunningApplication isActive call uses this API in some way, would anyone know how? I'm trying to do this in plain C on OSX/MacOS.

Comment: I doubt it. That's not information the kernel knows about a process. It's specific to the user session and is probably managed by the Window Server. An app can query the Window Server for information that's not available via system calls. At first it won't seem relevant, but read through [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2083/_index.html) for some useful info.

Comment: @KenThomases Thanks, that's interesting. I've been looking at APIs that interact with the window server. One seems to be CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo, for which apple have a sample: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SonOfGrab/ doesn't look like it exposes whether or not an app or window is the one in front. If you have ideas, they're appreciated.

Comment: Alternatives to the above might end up more intensive that just using the NSRunningApplication APIs, in which case I won't transition. Need to keep digging.